Converting a series object to a dataframe with columns from index and values from lists
I have a series object that contains the index as column names and the values for the columns are as lists. Looks like this as an example :
'A'  [100, 200, 300]
'B'  [400, 500, 600]

Of course I would like the dataframe to be :



A
B




100
400


200
500


300
600



I tried using reset_index, to_frame, or transpose, but just got weird flattened shapes and not in the desired table structure. I am sure the answer is simple and I am missing something!
In the real world, I will have as much as 50 to 100 columns and millions of rows.

Can you create your input using code?  I am not totally sure of the structure of your input object?

The datatypes come in so many varieties. Long strings to bools or large floats. It's financial data from a variety of databases and teams.

Where are you getting the series from? It seems like it would be easier to fix the problem at the source.

Assuming the input as:
s = pd.Series({'A': [100, 200, 300],
               'B': [400, 500, 600]})

Convert to_dict and use the DataFrame constructor:
df = pd.DataFrame(s.to_dict())

Alternatively:
df = pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(), index=s.index).T

# or
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(*s), columns=s.index)

Output:
     A    B
0  100  400
1  200  500
2  300  600


Sorry for the late reply and thank you for your solutions. I believe this : df = pd.DataFrame(zip(*s), columns=s.index) would work for me. I tried this with a 4M * 16 dataset and the speed was super fast (<10 seconds) I have tried the to_dict before and it is quite slow in our proprietary python environment. I will do more testing with larger datasets (>20M rows ) and let you know. Then I will mark it as the acceptable solution.

That would make sense, the to_dict/to_list approaches first create a complete intermediate in memory before DataFrame can use it. zip is creating a generator. Note that zip truncates the list to the size of the shortest one, itertools.zip should be used if the lists don't all have the same length.

I checked with 20M * 63 and 79M * 19 and the performance was satisfactory. Will update main thread. Thank you again!

just an aside, the * does create a tuple
